# Is no one using the ERC1820 standard? I don't see any activity on the chain

Tags: contract-development, erc-20

https://etherscan.io/address/0x1820a4B7618BdE71Dce8cdc73aAB6C95905faD24

ERC777 seems like it's clearly superior to ERC20 to me, there are security implications related to UX that make it preferable. Also, the OpenZeppelin team has created a solid implementation. I would expect that if people are using ERC777, we should see activity at the ERC1820 contract, which the OpenZeppelin team has hard-coded to the above address (0x1820...aD24). Is this not the right address? Is no one using ERC777?

Comment: How standards proliferate https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: you can send tokens on behalf of the user with ERC20 too. That's how everyone is doing it. So no need for ERC777